# using do-while and skipping the next lines

Tags: c#, .net, do-while

I want to run a method `_doing()` that loops infinitely until a `shutdownEvent` is triggered. This is basically executed/started on a `new Thread()`. But I need not `_doSomething` if it is `true` somewhere. what should i do after `if (_doSomething)`? Code snippet below. Thanks.

```
private HighResolutionLapseTimer _lapseTimer;

private int _timeToNext
{
    get
    {
        int lapseTime = _lapseTimer.LapseTime();
        int next = DO_PERIOD - lapseTime;

        if (next > 0)
        {
            return next;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int DO_PERIOD = 60000;

private void _doing()
{
    int _nextDoing = DO_PERIOD;
    Thread.Sleep(_nextDoing);

    do
    {
        LogInfo("Starting _doing");
        lock (this)
        {
            if (_doSomething)
            {
                // skip this time because we are currently archiving
            }
            _doSomething = true;
        }

        try
        {
            _lapseTimer.Start();
            DoSomethingHere(); //takes long processing
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                _nextDoing = (int)_timeToNext;
                _doSomething = false;
            }
        }
    } while (!shutdownWaitHandle.WaitOne(_nextDoing, false));

    LogInfo("Stopping _doing");
}
```

Comment: Seems like you basically have it; what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea what to put below the `if` statement. It is commented above. The previous code uses a `Timer` class so basically it just `return` and does nothing but I wanted to change the implementation of the `Timer_Elapsed` event to a single threaded function but I do not know how to implement it using a closed loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx); statement.

Comment: thanks bro. I just realized it just now, too. Thanks!

Comment: No probs, sometimes when writing the problem the solution presents itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ohw! I just realized that a `do-while` is similar to a `while`. And to 'skip' the execution, you just have to use the `continue;` if the `if statement` is true